# How can we set the working directory to the folder being selectecd in Rshiny?

Tags: input, shiny, directory

Please help find a way to set the folder being selected to be the working directory.

This code is for the server side:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # dir
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'dir', roots = c(home = 'c:'), filetypes = c('', 'txt', 'csv'))
  dir <- reactive(input$dir)
  output$dir <- renderPrint(dir())
  # path
  path <- reactive({
    home <- normalizePath("~")
    file.path(home, paste(unlist(dir()$path[-1]), collapse = .Platform$file.sep))
  })
  # files
  output$files <- renderPrint(list.files(path()))
})
```

This code is for the UI side:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    shinyDirButton("dir", "Chose directory", "Upload")
  ),
  mainPanel(
  ) 
)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your expected result but please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    shinyDirButton("dir", "Chose directory", "Upload")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("dir")
  ) 
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shinyDirChoose(input, id = 'dir', defaultRoot = getwd(), roots = setNames(c('.', 'c:'), c(getwd(), "home")), filetypes = c('', 'txt', 'csv'))
  output$dir <- renderUI({
    req(all(c("path", "root") %in% names(input$dir)))
    file.path(input$dir$root, paste0(input$dir$path, collapse = ""))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```